ideals in a (generalized) number ring are cofinite
Let $R$ be a domain whose fraction field is a number field $K$. If $p$ is a prime number, why is $R/pR$ finite?
This mentioned in the paper "Arithmetic in Number Rings" (where by number rings, they don't only mean $\mathcal{O}_K$, but any domain in a number field) by Cohen and Stevenhagen without comment (so I assume should be easy to see), where it is also claimed size of $R/pR$ is bounded by $p^{[K:Q]}$ ($p$ does not have to be a prime, but I have reduced to that case).
If $R$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-finite, such as $\mathcal{O}_K$ then this is clear to me, but if not, I don't see the argument.

In an obvious way, $R/pR$ is an $\mathbf F_p$-vector space. We'll prove it has dimension at most $[K:\mathbf Q]$, which implies $|R/pR| \leq p^{[K:\mathbf Q]}$. The argument presented below is inspired by the proof that a finite extension of $\mathbf Q_p$ with degree $n$ has residue field degree at at most $n$.  In that sense what I present below is a very standard argument, but you just may not have seen it applied in the particular context of number rings.
Let there be an $\mathbf F_p$-linearly independent subset $\overline{x_1}, \ldots, \overline{x_m}$ in $R/pR$. We'll show that $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ is a $\mathbf Q$-linearly independent subset of $K$, so $m \leq [K:\mathbf Q]$. Thus $R/pR$ is finite dimensional with dimension at most $[K:\mathbf Q]$.
Suppose there is a $\mathbf Q$-linear relation
$$
c_1x_1 + \cdots + c_mx_m = 0
$$
with $c_i \in \mathbf Q$. Multiply through by a common denominator of the $c_i$'s so we can assume each $c_i$ is in $\mathbf Z$.
The number of nonzero $c_i$'s initially is equal to the number of nonzero $c_i$'s after clearing the denominators.
Since each $c_i$ is in $\mathbf Z$ and each $x_i$ is in $R$, we can reduce both sides mod $pR$ to get
$$
\overline{c_1}\,\overline{x_1} + \cdots + \overline{c_m}\,\overline{x_m} = \overline{0}
$$
in $R/pR$. By $\mathbf F_p$-linear independence of the $\overline{x_i}$'s, each $\overline{c_i}$ is zero, so $p \mid c_i$ for all $i$.
Now go back to the linear relation
$c_1x_1 + \cdots + c_mx_m = 0$ and divide each $c_i$ by $p$. This gives us again a $\mathbf Z$-linear relation, and again each coefficient is divisible by $p$.  We can repeat this arbitrarily many times, so the initial $c_i$'s are divisible arbitrarily highly by $p$. That implies they are all $0$, so $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ is a $\mathbf Q$-linearly independent set.

It's faster to write down the argument without (pseudo-) contradiction. A direct proof will work. Also, you don't need to treat the case R/pR = 0 separately.

@MartinBrandenburg Alright, the answer has been updated.
